# North America version of BBC Radiophonic Workshop (RE: Sound FX)

Tags: sound-effects, distribution

I'm re-watching The Twilight Zone and The Outer Limits and have heard several different sound FX and sound samples that I know were used in other shows like Star Trek (TOS).

Does anyone know if there was a North American group/unit (c. 1950-70's) that was similarly important/influential upon the SciFi community as the BBC Radiophonic Workshop?

Comment: It seems unlikely. At the time, the BBC was the only broadcaster in the U.K. and so was the only place to go; the US had ABC, NBC, and CBS as well as potentially other now defunct broadcasters each with their own sound effects departments.

Comment: @ James McLeod Good point. Do you thnk/know of anyone within that US sphere that may have been like Delia Derbyshire or Gino Marinuzzi, Jr. besides, say, Bebe and Louis Barron...?

Comment: I don't even know who you are talking about...

Comment: [Delia's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delia_Derbyshire) awesome! I'm not sure there's a direct analog in the US. Are you looking for pioneers in electronic instrumentation (like [Don Buchla](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don_Buchla) and [Bob Moog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Moog)), foley artists of the era, or electronic musicians?

Comment: Maybe [Raymond Scott](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raymond_Scott)?

Comment: @user1118321 Good point! The early pioneers would be, much like the UK/European tradition, likely crossed over between the two as Derbyshire did--should of seen that! Thanks!

Comment: He's not so much SF as the alternate reality of cartoons. But I think he may be closest to what you are looking for in terms of avant guard jazz + early electronic music. Unless you bring in your theremin...